# Are immutable globalThis variables possible in JS?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, es6-modules

Is there a way to make

```
globalThis.variable = value
```

`const`, `final`, `readonly`...?

It would make sense to have global cross-modules variables that are readonly. Of course manually exporting variables makes them immutable in other modules, but it's not the same luxury as just having global variables (that I can just call anywhere, without having to import everywhere).

Comment: "*it's not the same luxury as just having global variables*" that's not a luxury. Quite the opposite. If you're *right now* struggling with overwriting globals and your solution is to make them immutable, then you've not solved the problem. If you have some code that does `globalThis.variable = newValue` that will either fail with an error in strict mode or just silently fail, thus leaving you possibly wondering why it didn't work.

Comment: A strong desire to use global variables is not really a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I don't have any problems, the code is bug-free and fairly coherent. Most is managed by explicit exports / imports, but there're a few constants that are used widely. So I thought going global might be appropriate for these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) with `writable: false`:

```
Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'variable', {
  value,
  writable: false,
});
```

Examples:

Silently ignores without `"use strict";`

```js
Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'variable', {
  value: 123,
  writable: false,
});

console.log(variable);
variable = 567;
console.log(variable);
```

Error with `"use strict";`

```js
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'variable', {
  value: 123,
  writable: false,
});

console.log(variable);
variable = 567;
console.log(variable);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I've been looking for.